# Display example of database in Latex - style is in Stackoverflow

Tags: latex, styles

I want to display this example of a AIS database in Latex in the same style as is done in Stackoverflow, how do I do this in Latex:

```
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13`gcphP000FeiVMuT3>4?wD20S1,0*1D
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,33MIo650000FFE>Mw:V00:iB0DSJ,0*1F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13`lS<@P00PFPwLMtUJN4?wD28Ht,0*4F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13aJIGwP0cPFMtNMv@k7rgwF2@I5,0*1A
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13aI9rUP19PFvwLMrLb@NgwF28I6,0*2D
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this sketch would be close to the current webpage font style:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,verbatim}

\begin{document}

\setmonofont{Consolas}
\begin{verbatim}
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13`gcphP000FeiVMuT3>4?wD20S1,0*1D
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,33MIo650000FFE>Mw:V00:iB0DSJ,0*1F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13`lS<@P00PFPwLMtUJN4?wD28Ht,0*4F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13aJIGwP0cPFMtNMv@k7rgwF2@I5,0*1A
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13aI9rUP19PFvwLMrLb@NgwF28I6,0*2D
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

but LuaTeX or LuaLaTeX are required to compile if we use the package `fontspec`. Otherwise just:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13`gcphP000FeiVMuT3>4?wD20S1,0*1D
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,33MIo650000FFE>Mw:V00:iB0DSJ,0*1F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13`lS<@P00PFPwLMtUJN4?wD28Ht,0*4F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13aJIGwP0cPFMtNMv@k7rgwF2@I5,0*1A
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13aI9rUP19PFvwLMrLb@NgwF28I6,0*2D
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

or either:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spverbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{spverbatim}
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13`gcphP000FeiVMuT3>4?wD20S1,0*1D
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,33MIo650000FFE>Mw:V00:iB0DSJ,0*1F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13`lS<@P00PFPwLMtUJN4?wD28Ht,0*4F
!AIVDM,1,1,,B,13aJIGwP0cPFMtNMv@k7rgwF2@I5,0*1A
!AIVDM,1,1,,A,13aI9rUP19PFvwLMrLb@NgwF28I6,0*2D
\end{spverbatim}

\end{document}
```

would work if compiled with just PDFLaTeX.

Does this fit or did I misunderstand your question?